# Using ADTF File Library

Tags: c++, windows, adtf

I wanted to use [ADTF](https://github.com/cariad-tech/adtf_file) library in my visual studio project. Do i need to build the library from my machine to use it? The instructions provided with the library are not clear to me since i haven't used cmake build before.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The doumentation says *"The libraries are build and tested only under following compilers and operating systems: Windows 7 64 Bit, Visual Studio C++ 2015 Update 3.1"* With that limitation, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Don't we need .lib files to add it to VS project? Please correct me if i'm wrong. I cant see any of this kind in the repository.

Comment: A repository should normally only contain source code to build the package (library in your case). What you need is a prebuild package which can be hosted on different platforms (e.g. as package in github, artifactory or any other package manager or download center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following instructions are for ADTF File Library 0.7:

**Linux**

1. First build a_util
   `$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<any-install-dir> -Da_util_cmake_enable_documentation=OFF -Da_util_cmake_enable_integrated_tests=OFF . && make && make install`
2. Then build ddl
   `$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<any-install-dir> -Da_util_DIR=<a_util-install-dir-given-above> -Dddl_cmake_enable_documentation=OFF -Dddl_cmake_enable_tests=OFF -Dddl_cmake_enable_generator_tools=OFF -Dddl_cmake_enable_installation=ON . && make && make install`
3. Then build ifhd
   `$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<any-install-dir> -Da_util_DIR=<a_util-install-dir-given-above> -Dddl_DIR=<ddl-install-dir-given-above> -Difhd_cmake_enable_documentation=OFF -Difhd_cmake_enable_integrated_tests=OFF . && make && make install`

**Windows**
cmake steps remain the same. It will generate visual studio solution that you can use to build and edit.

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, the documentation is grab and outdated. Also the repository is not up to date mirrored from internal development. But you do not have to compile the package by yourself, you can access the ADTF File Library / IFHD directly as prebuild package, either standalone or within ADTF delivery. All you need to know you will find [here](https://support.digitalwerk.net/projects/download-center/wiki/Overview_of_Products_and_Documentation). The current version is 0.9.0 and has been released yesterday for VS2019 VC142, gcc7 (x86_64 and aarch64).